# Learning Curve in Q-learning

Tags: c++, reinforcement-learning, q-learning

My question is I wrote the Q-learning algorithm in c++ with epsilon greedy policy now I have to plot the learning curve for the Q-values. What exactly I should have to plot because I have an 11x5 Q matrix, so should I take one Q value and plot its learning or should I have to take the whole matrix for a learning curve, could you guide me with it.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Learning curves in RL are typically plots of **returns** over time, not Q-losses or anything like this. So you should run your environment, compute the total reward (aka return) and plot it at a corresponding time.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So that means I have to add all the values of reward coming from the environment at different actions taken and plot it? But isn't Q learning all ready doing it using a Bellman equation?

Comment: Yes that's what you need to do. Bellman equation looks at Q values, not actual rewards.

Answer (score 0):

For learning curves in Q-learning, it's common to print the cumulative reward per episode. Typically, you would accumulate the reward at each time step within an episode and print or visualize the cumulative reward after the episode is completed.